# Getting NaN In Building a Simple Calculator

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new to Javascript and I'm currently working on a simple calculator that would allow users to answer a few questions in order to calculate their total price. The price would show up in the DIV below the form. But, the issue that I'm having is that the output in the div is NaN until the last option is selected.

The code isn't perfect since I'm just testing at this point, but here's the HTML.

```js
const looks  = document.getElementById('looks');
const edits  = document.getElementById('edits');
const studio = document.getElementById('studio');
const total  = document.getElementById('total');
const btn    = document.getElementById('btn')

looks.addEventListener('change', totalCost);
edits.addEventListener('change', totalCost);
studio.addEventListener('change', totalCost);
btn.addEventListener('click', totalCost);


function totalCost() {
  total.innerText = (looks.value * 100) 
                  + (edits.value * 50) 
                  + parseInt(studio.value);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form action="">
    <h3>How Many Looks?</h3> 

    <input type="number" id="looks" value="">
    <h3>How Many Edits?</h3>
    <input type="number" id="edits" value="">
    <h3>Location:</h3>
    <select name="studio" id="studio">
      <option value="">On-Location</option>
      <option value="100">In-Studio</option>
    </select>
    <h3>Total:</h3>
    <div id="total"></div>
    <input type="button" value="submit" id="btn">
  </form>
</div>
```

I'd also like to implement something where the total doesn't show up until the submit button is pressed. I'd greatly appreciate any help in these matters. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You have an issue in `studio.value`, its come NaN for first init, you need to check your param if its number or not before do a calculation or convert it to number like below example:

```js
const looks  = document.getElementById('looks');
const edits  = document.getElementById('edits');
const studio = document.getElementById('studio');
const total  = document.getElementById('total');
const btn    = document.getElementById('btn')

looks.addEventListener('change', totalCost);
edits.addEventListener('change', totalCost);
studio.addEventListener('change', totalCost);
btn.addEventListener('click', totalCost);


function totalCost() {
  let stdValue = parseInt(studio.value);
  if(isNaN(stdValue)){
    stdValue = 0;
  }

  total.innerText = ((looks.value * 100) 
                  + (edits.value * 50) 
                  + stdValue);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form action="">
    <h3>How Many Looks?</h3> 

    <input type="number" id="looks" value="">
    <h3>How Many Edits?</h3>
    <input type="number" id="edits" value="">
    <h3>Location:</h3>
    <select name="studio" id="studio">
      <option value="">On-Location</option>
      <option value="100">In-Studio</option>
    </select>
    <h3>Total:</h3>
    <div id="total"></div>
    <input type="button" value="submit" id="btn">
  </form>
</div>
```

====================

#### Update 1:

Like Nick Parsons Suggestion, the real answer must be via set the 0 as a default option if its needed as a number...

```
<option value="0">On-Location</option>
```

So that, look when and where you need to validate and when need to setup initial value...do both to get a good code...

Comment: It would be more straight-foward to set the value in the option to 0: `<option value="0">On-Location</option>`

Comment: Would there be another way to set the price for that particular option if the value is zero?

Answer (score 0):

this way

```js
const 
    myForm = document.getElementById('my-form')
  , total  = document.getElementById('total')
  ;
myForm.oninput = evt =>
  {
  total.textContent = (myForm.looks.valueAsNumber * 100) 
                    + (myForm.edits.valueAsNumber * 50) 
                    + (parseInt(myForm.studio.value) || 0)
  }
myForm.onsubmit = evt => // beter than btn.onclick
  {
  evt.preventDefault() // stop form submiting
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form action="" id="my-form">
    <h3>How Many Looks?</h3> 
    <input type="number" name="looks" value="0" min="0">
    <h3>How Many Edits?</h3>
    <input type="number" name="edits" value="0" min="0">
    <h3>Location:</h3>
    <select name="studio"  >
      <option value=""  selected > On-Location </option>
      <option value="100"         > In-Studio   </option>
    </select>
    <h3>Total:</h3>
    <div id="total"> ? </div>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```